# Pandas - Merging and Comparing two DataFrames (one unique column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get that this is a common question but there are so many variations on it in pandas that I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I have two DataFrames - one for `today` and one for `yesterday` and would like to create two new df's using both as inputs.

Based on my single Unique column - the comparison between the two df's can have one of three outputs.

1. The Unique Key is in both `today` and `yesterday`
2. The Unique Key is in `today` but not `yesterday`
3. The Unique Key is not `today` but is in `yesterday`

The first df I would like to merge the df's such that it outputs #1 & #2, with the values in `yesterday` taking precedence AND adding any additional columns from `yesterday`.

The second output I simply want to output #3.

Using some examples:

today

```
index c1 c2 unique
1     x  y  14A
2     x  y  15A
4     x  y  17A
5     x  y  18A
6     x  y  19A
```

yesterday

```
index c1 c2 unique c3
1     a  b  14A    z
2     a  b  15A    z
3     a  b  16A    z
4     a  b  17A    z
```

output1 (#1 & #2)

```
index c1 c2 unique c3
1     a  b  14A    z
2     a  b  15A    z
4     a  b  17A    z
5     x  y  18A
6     x  y  19A
```

output2 (#3)

```
index c1 c2 unique c3
3     a  b  16A    z
```

A few extra things:

- I have been trying to use `pd.merge` for #1, I would really like to not have `_x` and `_y` duplicate columns when merging.
- I tried `yest[~yest['UniqueKey'].isin(today['UniqueKey'])]` for #3 and I think it works?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution for first requirement(output1 & output2)

```
case1 = yesterday[yesterday['unique'].isin(today['unique'])] 

case2 = today[~today['unique'].isin(yesterday['unique'])]

output_1_2 = case1.append(case2, ignore_index = True)
output_1_2.replace(np.nan, "", regex = True) # to replace NaN
```

For second requirement(output3), your approach works.

Answer (score 4):

For output #3, you may try with :

```
DataFrame.join(other_Dataframe, how = 'right')
```

You can follow: [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pandas.DataFrame.join)

Answer (score 1):

output 1(#1 & #2) can be obtained using `pandas.DataFrame.combine_first`

if not already done, set the `unique` column as the data frame's index

```
today = today.set_index('unique')
yesterday = yesterday.set_index('unique')
```

then,

```
yesterday[yesterday.index.isin(today.index)].combine_first(today).reset_index()
  unique c1 c2   c3  index
0    14A  a  b    z    1.0
1    15A  a  b    z    2.0
2    17A  a  b    z    4.0
3    18A  x  y  NaN    5.0
4    19A  x  y  NaN    6.0
```

output 2(#3) can be obtained using the set difference of the two indices & `.loc`, or better yet using negated `isin` & boolean indexing

```
yesterday[~yesterday.index.isin(today.index)]
# or: yesterday.loc[list(set(yesterday.index) - set(today.index))]
# both produce the following output:
  unique  index c1 c2 c3
0    16A      3  a  b  z
```

Comment: Good one. But i believe unique 16A should not come for first dataframe(output of 1&2 conditions).